# Why does ArrayList print the actual value and not the memory address?

Tags: java, arraylist, reference

In Java, I understand primitive data types are stored as a value and the rest are stored as references. Then why is it that I get the actual value but not the memory address when I print ArrayList instance variable? I have an array variable just for comparing purposes.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object[] a = new Object[3];
        a[0] = 0;
        a[1] = 1;
        a[2] = 2;

        ArrayList<Object> b = new ArrayList<Object>();
        b.add(3);
        b.add(4);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);

    }
```

Comment: Because the `toString()` method has been overridden.  Because the javadocs say it does.   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons

- Because the `Object.toString()` method has been overridden.
- Because the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--) says that the `toString()` method for any type that extends the `AbstractCollection` class will display the collection's contents, not its "address".

And besides `Object.toString()` doesn't actually display the address anyway.  It displays the identity hashcode with *might* be related to the address of the object, or it might not.  (And two distinct objects can have the same identity hashcode, so it is not a reliable indicator that objects are the same.)

If you want to test if two object references (of any type) refer to the  same object, use `==`.

You don't need to look at addresses, and even if you figure out how to get the real address of an object ... object addresses change when the GC moves them, so this may not a 100% reliable way to test the objects.

Comment: I see. It's the hashcode to be exact. Thank you

Comment: To be  exact, it is the >identity< hashcode.  The `hashCode()` method could be overridden to return a different hashcode.  But the default `toString()` method uses the identity hashcode ... directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can discover why on your own. Just follow the documentation.

The `println` method takes a `String` object. See [its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)). To quote:

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

That means a call is made to the `toString` method on the collection object you pass to `println`.

So look at the Javadoc for the [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) method inherited by `ArrayList`. To quote:

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

Answer (score 0):

It's because it implements the `toString()` method.  The default output is the hash code.  [Memory Address of Objects in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-object-memory-address) documents how to get the memory address